# Windows Server Backup 2012 error - "The version does not support this version of the file format."

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012

I'm trying out Windows Server 2012, specifically Windows Server Backup, as it would be a very useful way to see us through until we can upgrade our 'real' backup system.

I'm backing up to a network share, and a Server 2008 WSB works fine.

On the 2012 server however, I get an error:

> Backup of volume \?\Volume{298d1a7d-f80f-11e1-93e8-806e6f6e6963}\ has failed. The version does not support this version of the file format.

It's a VHDX written by WSB, so I'm not sure what version it's complaining about.

I can see a whole bunch of files in the destination, so I don't think it's a simple authentication issue, but I only get about 8Mb of VHDX written.

Answer (score 3):

We have had similar issues to Linux based NAS's in server 2012 when 2008 also worked fine.

The issue for us was based on the SAMBA sparse files allocation setting.

Modifying this on the NAS fixed the issue. There are some details of how to do that and some links below:

http://kb.backupassist.com/articles.php?aid=3298

Specifically, adding an option to the `smb.conf` file:

```
strict allocate = yes
```

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue backing up Virtual machines on Server 2012 to Simpana.  Turned out the issue was the new VHDX file format, converting to VHD fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create A VHD in the network location by steps below:

1-Create a VHD via Disk Management in windows

2-locate the location of the new VHD in the location you need to backup into your situation will be in the network share location.

3-check mark on make the VHD expandable to increase the performance

4-After creating the VHD its attached to your windows and will act as a normal harddisk you can specify the backup to